# HTML5 video not loading in chrome

Tags: html5-video

I am using video.js to implement the video and the following code:

.htaccess:

```
AddType text/x-component .htc

AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/ogg .ogv .ogg
```

HTML:

```
 <video id="video-1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
                             width="100%" height="100%"
                              poster="videos/timelapse.jpg"
                             data-setup='{ "controls": true, "autoplay": false, "preload": "auto" }'>
                         <source src="videos/timelapse.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
                         <source src="videos/timelapse.webm" type='video/webm' />
                         <source src="videos/timelapse.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
                          Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.
                        <a href="videos/timelapse.mp4">Download</a> the video instead.
                        </video>
```

I get the following error in chrome:

```
["Video Error", Object]
0: "Video Error"
1: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

However if i change the order of the formats and put the .webm first it works in chrome but not in firefox.

Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using mp4 and ogg is enough, and should work on ie9+, opera 10.6+, chrome 6+, firefox 3.6+ and safari 5+.

```
<source src="videos/timelapse.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="videos/timelapse.ogg" type="video/ogg">
```

Comment: no doesn't work in google chrome still, no error, but stays on loading gif